# Azure Pipelines download dependent GitHub release

Tags: azure, github, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created  ASP.NET Core Pipeline for my project on Azure DevOps.
And to successfully build it i need to download some dependent  source repositories i have on github.

Need help with configuring the pipeline yaml that the dependend github sources.
The file structure to build the project should be something like this:

```
Birko.Data // Github repo 
Birko.Data.Helper // Github repo 
Birko.Data.ElasticSearch // Github repo 
Affiliate  // Azure dev ops repo
  - project sources
  -.sln file
```

If I understand this correct all the sources are downloaded to the `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)` so the Githubs repos need to be in parent directory?

pipeline definition YAML:

```
    trigger:
    - master

    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'

    variables:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'

    steps:
    - task: DownloadGitHubRelease@0
      displayName: 'Chekout: Birko.Data'
      inputs:
        connection: 'birko-test'
        userRepository: 'birko/Birko.Data'
        defaultVersionType: 'latest'
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

    - task: DownloadGitHubRelease@0
      displayName: 'Chekout: Birko.Data.Helper'
      inputs:
        connection: 'birko-test'
        userRepository: 'birko/Birko.Data.Helper'
        defaultVersionType: 'latest'
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

    - task: DownloadGitHubRelease@0
      displayName: 'Chekout Birko.Data.ElasticSearch'
      inputs:
        connection: 'birko-test'
        userRepository: 'birko/Birko.Data.ElasticSearch'
        defaultVersionType: 'latest'
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: VSTest@2
      inputs:
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the sources are download to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` that is the `s` folder in the agent (e.g. `D:\a\1\s`).

So if in your Azure DevOps repo you have multiple folders and files in the repository root you will get them in the folder `s`, and according to your structure you should download the GitHub repos to the parent folder. but, if in your Azure DevOps repo there is a one folder and in this folder there are more files and folders so in the `s` you will see only the folder (with sub folders and files), and in this case you need to download the GitHub repos to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`.

If the first case is true I'm not recommended to download to the parent folder, maybe you need to consider to write a small PowerShell script that create a new folder in the `s`, move all the Azure DevOps files to there and then download to `s` the GitHub repos.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  You were right. after moving the files and  then cloning the GitHub repositories the build was finally a success